# Using SOAPUI as a kind of gateway

Tags: eclipse, web-services, groovy, soapui

I want to ask you if it is possible in SOAPUI to alter a mock response, and link it to the real web service operation in which the MockService is based on.

I need to do that because within SOAPUI I can reach to external webservices; BUT for security/configuration reasons, I can’t access to this external webservices inside my local code in my Eclipse (I have tried several proxy configurations in my Eclipse without success).

What I want to do is to pass the request that reach to the mock service to the original web service and return the response without manipulation.

Comment: Have you checked soapui's [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/mock-services.html)?

Comment: Yes I did, but I havent found what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a *mockService* in *SOAPUI* to redirect your request to a 3rd party service as follows:

First creat a *mockService* in your project: **right click on your project > New SOAP MockService**

[image]

Then creat a *mockOperation* on it: **right click on your MockService > New MockOperation**

[image]

Inside your *mockOperation* there is a *request* created, open it an put for example the follow code as a response: `${myResponse}`. This name is bind to a variable which will fill then with a script.

[image]

Finally open your *mockOperation* and use the follow script to hit your 3rd party service redirecting the original request:

```
final HttpURLConnection connection = 'http://yourService:8080'.toURL().openConnection()

connection.setDoOutput(true)
// copy the headers
mockRequest.getRequestHeaders().each { name, value ->
    connection.setRequestProperty(name,value.toString())
}
// write the request 
connection.outputStream.withWriter { Writer writer ->
    writer << mockRequest.requestContent
}
// get the response
String response = connection.inputStream.withReader { Reader reader -> reader.text }
// set the response in your variable
requestContext.myResponse = response
```

[image]

Hope this helps,

Comment: It seems to be a right answer; but I get a java.net.SocketException: Socket is not connected. (I have tried several Proxy settings without succeed)

Comment: @webmeiker I know that probably you can't... but can you share the url of the service to reproduce your `java.net.SocketException`?

Comment: Doesnt matter I'll give you the bounty. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @webmeiker thanks `:)`... however this doesn't work for you? If you need more help tell me.

Comment: I open a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36570950/how-to-invoke-a-concrete-operation-of-a-mock-service-deployed-in-soapui   (in case you want to help me again)

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it turning 'Dispatch' to SCRIPT and adding this script:

```
// import all the namespaces to trim the lines of codes
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlInterface
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlRequest
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmitContext
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit
import com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Response
import com.eviware.soapui.model.mock.MockResponse

// get reference to project
WsdlProject project = (WsdlProject)mockOperation.mockService.project

// get reference to request
WsdlRequest request = (WsdlRequest)project.interfaces["TheRealWebService"].operations["TheRealOperation"].getRequestByName("TheRealRequest")

// set request content from incoming mockRequest
request.setRequestContent(mockRequest.getRequestContent())

// submit request asynchronously
WsdlSubmit submit=request.submit( new WsdlSubmitContext( request ), false )

// wait for the response
Response response = submit.getResponse();

// get reference to MockResponse
MockResponse mockResponse=mockOperation.getMockResponseByName("Response1")

// set the mock response content from response received by the request.
mockResponse.setResponseContent(response.getContentAsString())
```