# How to invoke a concrete operation of a Mock service deployed in SOAPUI

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui

I have one SoapUI Mock service (served as `http://localhost:8454/MyMock`) with several operations MockOpA, MockOpB, MockOpC... each of them with his particular unic response.

Is there a way to invoke a particular operation adding it to the URL I used inside the Java code that calls the Mock Service?

Something like `http://localhost:8454/MyMock/MockOpA`.

I see a lot of examples of one operation several responses; but none of several operations exposed by the same Mock Service.

Comment: May be you can show what you tried, and the issue that would help for others.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

[image]

I have found what I need .....

[image]